Motives and birational invariance
One can construct non-isomorphic smooth projective varieties which define the same motive by blowing up $\mathbb{P}^2$ at five points. I think I learned this here at MathOverflow. But these examples are all birational.
Are there any examples of non-birational smooth projective varieties which define the same motive?
More generally, how does one go about understanding the relation/difference between birational invariants and motivic invariants?

A counter-example is given by fake projective planes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_projective_plane

Or an Enriques surface vs. a blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at nine points... Here there is even a known construction of an isomorphism in the category of Chow motives (an explicit algebraic cycle on the product).

And conversely, birational varieties rarely have isomorphic motives (or even isomorphic cohomology). The two problems are pretty different in general.

@PiotrAchinger: Can you give a reference to a construction of such a cycle?

The coefficients you want to use in the definition of motive should be specified, since for a particular example the motives could be isomorphic rationally but not integrally.

@DanielLoughran: This is conjectured to be true, but I don't think it has actually been proved (at least in the category of Chow motives). Also, this does not hold integrally for any fake projective plane.

@Sasha my notes say it's in Bloch-Kas-Lieberman "Zero cycles on surfaces with $p_g=0$" (Compositio 1976). But now looking at that paper I am not so sure anymore. They do construct a correspondence between an Enriques and the relative Jacobian of its elliptic fibration, and then show the latter is a rational surface (presumably it then has to be the blowup of $\mathbf{P}^2$ at the intersection of two cubics?). But the paper is about zero-cycles and the statement is preserved by birational equivalence, one would have to check what it says about Chow motives.

@PiotrAchinger: Anyway, thanks for the reference!

@PiotrAchinger: My notes say that Proposition 3.1 of K. Coombes "The $K$-cohomology of Enriques surfaces", Contemp. Math 126, (1992) proves this for Chow motives with $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$-coefficients, though I haven't had time to double check. There is also some generalisation (but only with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients ) in the recent paper D. Kawabe, "Chow motives of genus one fibrations", Manuscripta Math. 175 (2024).

@OliGregory: thanks for the references!

This is probably not the kind of example you are looking for, but you can get an example with Artin motives using rational coefficients and $\mathbb{Q}$ as the base field.
Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a finite Galois extension with group $G$. Then $\mathrm{Spec}\,K$ is a smooth projective (not geometrically connected) variety over $\mathbb{Q}$, whose motive I will denote $M_K$. The subcategory of motives generated by $M_K$ is identified with the category of representations of $G$, where $M_K$ corresponds to the regular representation. For each subgroup $H\leq G$, the motive $M_{K^H}$ of the fixed field of $H$ corresponds to the permutation representation of $G$ on $G/H$.
Now, isomorphism classes of subfields of $K$ correspond to conjugacy classes of subgroups $H\leq G$, and isomorphism classes of representations of $G$ can be identified with class functions on $G$. So if there are more conjugacy classes of subgroups of $G$ than there are conjugacy classes of elements of $G$, there must be two distinct unions of subfields whose motives correspond to the same class function on $G$, i.e. whose motives are isomorphic.
We can get a concrete example with $G=S_3$. There are four conjugacy classes of subgroups of $G$, represented by the subgroups $\{1\}$, $\langle (12)\rangle$, $\langle (123)\rangle$, and $G$. Let $V_1,\ldots,V_4$ be the permutations representations corresponding to these subgroups, respectively. There are only three conjugacy classes in $G$, so there must be a relation among the characters of these representations. If I computed correctly, the relation is
$$
V_1\oplus V_4\oplus V_4\cong V_2\oplus V_2\oplus V_3.
$$
So e.g. taking $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$ (with $\zeta_3$ a primitive third root of unity), the varieties
$$
\mathrm{Spec}\, \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)\sqcup \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Q}\sqcup \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Q}
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\sqcup \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\sqcup \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)
$$
have isomorphic motives. These varieties are smooth and projective, but not connected.
